# How do I change my font in VS Code because clearly this is giving me the wrong output

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

I have tried to change to loads of different fonts in VS but they all just output as this. That is, anything other than the standard default fonts (monospace). For some reason it works for everyone but me!
Please help me out! Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlBRM.png)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you don't have the font installed, in this case Fira Code.

You can download it from their [repository](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode), specifically from this [link](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/tree/master/distr/ttf), and [install](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/Installing) it in your system.

There's a wide [variety](https://www.creativebloq.com/features/the-best-monospace-fonts-for-coding) of monospace fonts you can try.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Fira Code use this as your setting

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'Fira Code', monospace"
```

I recommend to use `Source Code Pro` with a replacement for the `a` glyph